# Pipeline stall after a load instruction but not after an add instruction

Tags: cpu-architecture

I am doing some question about pipelines. This one I need help with.

> Why can there be a pipeline stall after a load instruction but not after
>   an add instruction?

I know that a unused slot in the pipeline is called a pipeline stall. My guess is that it can be a pipeline stall after a load instruction because we need to wait for a register that might be updated. But I can not come up with an answer for why an add instruction can not create a pipeline stall. Maybe it is because at this stage there we have already read from a register?

Comment: Add is often only 1 cycle latency, so with forwarding (aka bypass) the result of an add can be used by the next instruction.  [This Q&A might be relevant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19041315/pipeline-stalling-and-bypassing-examples), but I didn't read it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A pipeline stall is used to resolve hazards usually caused by data dependencies. An add can actually produce a pipeline stall, but let's first consider an example in which it does not.

```
SUB r2, r3
ADD r1, r2
```

Even though the add instruction uses the result of the subtract, there is no stall. This is because the EX stage has access to the data from the previous EX stage.

Now let's consider an example in which an add can produce a stall.

```
LOAD r2, RAM[a]
ADD r1, r2
```

Here, data produced by the MEM stage from the load instruction is required as input by the EX stage of the ADD instruction. The EX stage only has access to the data from the previous EX stage, therefore stalling the pipeline due to a read after write hazard. This is illustrated by this diagram

[image]

This is resolved by introducing a bubble into the pipeline (like a NOP) which resolves the data dependency without needing to propagate data backwards in time (which is impossible).

[image]

You can learn more about this in much greater detail by reading up on [hazards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)), [bubbles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(computing)), and [forwarding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand_forwarding)

Comment: Data from a load being consumed by an add isn't really the `add` producing a stall, IMO.  I'd attribute that to the load, not the consumer, since loads produce their result later in the pipeline than ALU operations.

Comment: Also, do load-addresses need to be ready in the EX stage of this example of a classic RISC pipeline, or can it do pointer-chasing with 1c latency just forwarding loaded data from the MEM stage back into the MEM stage?

Comment: @PeterCordes I would argue that the add IS producing a stall. This is because without the instruction, a stall does not occur. Stalls are produced by the instruction that causes the data dependency. If you removed the add instruction, the stall would not occur. Therefore I would argue that the 'add' does produce the stall. As for your second question, pointer-chasing is made possible with operand forwarding. The same way the 'EX' stage can read data from the previous 'EX' stage, the 'MEM' stage can read data from the previous 'MEM' stage.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought the MEM output might have to go to the EX input, for addressing-modes with an offset.  (I guess with only one-register addressing modes, though, a dedicated AGU in the MEM stage is just an adder which you might need anyway.)  Re: blaming the add or the load: That's fair, it's really just scheduling them together that's the issue, not either one on its own.  I was looking at it from the perspective that if the input to the `add` had been produced by an ALU instruction instead of a load, there wouldn't be a stall.